# Thingspeak data visualisation/ graphs for webpage

Tags: javascript, charts, iot, weather

i want to make graphs/ charts from my data, that is stored on Thingspeak (its a weather station project using arduino). Now, i want to be able to plot these data into graphs. Thingspeak itself does that, but the graph is non customizable.

What i want do do is to have some buttons and comboboxes to select for example certain time interval (days,weeks,months), be able to point on line in graph and it tels the stats for the one spot etc.

Is there any templates or web services that do that? Or tutorials on how to do that? I want to have these charts embedde to my webpages. Thank you for replies.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at Chart JS or D3, both good charting libraries.